# How to get Json values by concating underscore(_)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Can anybody please help me how to get data in this JSON format `{"EMPLOYEE_DETAILS":"1-abc_xyz"}` not default format `{"id":1, "firstName":"abc", "lastName":"xyz"}` And data will be fetched from the specific column. Suppose in employee table `first_name = abc`, and `last_name = xyz`.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="employee") 
public class Employee{
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
     private int id;
     @Column(name = "first_name") 
     private String firstName;
     @Column(name = "last_name") 
     private String lastName;
     //Generate setters and getters 
}
```

Comment: I don't completly understand your question. What you want is not a mapping of your entity to JSON. So you may not use JSON serialization but directly produce the JSON result for example with GSON

Answer (score 1):

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-name-of-property

```
@JsonProperty("MY_NAME")
```

Above getters, or if using Lombok, above the fields